# I have the below errors when I try to run my android project in phone; I already switched "ON" Developer mode and USB Debugging

Tags: android

[com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw8wx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first connect a phone to a new computer via USB Debugging, it will pop up a confirmation dialog ont he phone asking if you want to let this device debug.  You need to click ok  (you may need to toggle USB debugging on and off again to see the dialog again).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right but I got "Because an app is obscuring a permission request, Settings can't verify your response" error when I try to press "OK" in USB debugging popup menu in my phone....
Soluction:
I got this solution,https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS8/comments/81r7xl/because_an_app_is_obscuring_a_permission_request/

What I do:
I uninstall night mode app from my mobile and now I am able to press ok button without any error.., and then app are installed in my mobile phone from Android Studio.